# How to use SELECT with WHERE & AND in conditional checks using PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql

On my server, I am attempting to find a specific string in a database table, if that string is found, I want to check to see what an integer value is in another field of the same row and UPDATE that integer if it is needed, or exit the PHP script.

The code below is only some of what I have tried.  I don't see what is incorrect with the commands, and there are no error messages produced when it is ran/called.

What happens is, if the string is found, the script automatically runs the $there query.

What do I need to do to make this work correctly?

Thank you very much.

```
// This script checks to see if a member name sent by the page exists in the database.

//-------------------------------------------------------------

// The database section starts here.
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "manager";
$password = "********";
$dbname = "golf_ledger";

//------------------------------

// Make a connection with the server.
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check the connection.
if($conn === false){
    die("ERROR: Couldn't connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else {
echo "The connection worked."."<br>"."<br>";
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------

// This is the test string to be searched for.
$memName = "Richardson";

//----------------------------------------

// Populate $result with the search query.
//                                                      Database name  Table name
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `golf_ledger`.`member_table` WHERE `member_table`.`name` = '$memName'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)  {
 echo "Sorry, the name was not found";   

die();

}

//----------------------------------------

// Something is wrong with this one, possibly.

$there = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `golf_ledger`.`member_table` WHERE `member_table`.`name` = '$memName' AND `member_table`.`pay_Status` =  1");

//  "if ($there)" is the same as "if ($there == true)" in PHP.

if ($there == true) {
echo "The name has been found, and they have paid.";

die();

}

//----------------------------------------

$notThere = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `golf_ledger`.`member_table` WHERE `member_table`.`name` = '$memName' AND `member_table`.`pay_Status` =  0");

if ($notThere == true) {
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `golf_ledger`.`member_table` SET `pay_Status` = 1 WHERE `member_table`.`name` = '$memName'");

echo "The name has been found, they have NOT paid, but the status has been updated.";

die();

}
```

Comment: show us db schema, sample data and desire output.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: `$there` is going to be true whether or not there is a result. You need to use `mysqli_num_rows` again.

Comment: @WheatBeak  thanks for the tip, but since my knowledge of MySql is limited, I didn't know how to use your tip to do what I wanted.

Comment: What I mean is, `mysql_query` will return true even if no rows are found because it's still a successful query, that's why you have to use `mysqli_num_rows` to make sure there are more than 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this code:

```
if ($there == true) {
    echo "The name has been found, and they have paid.";

    die();

}
```

try that:

```
// Check if found any records
if (mysqli_num_rows($there) > 0) {
    echo "The name has been found, and they have paid.";

    die();

}
```

Comment: Vasiliy, thanks, your example is just what I needed.  I hope it helps someone elso also.  I searched the 4,000+ page MySql manual, but didn't find what I was looking for.  How did you folks know about the procedure to do what I was asking?